# How to disable note log in mariadb error log?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am using centos 7.3 and Mariadb 10.3.
When I `cat /var/log/mariadb-error.log`, I found lots of `note` as below:

```
2018-10-16 15:07:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2018-10-16 15:07:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-10-16 15:07:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.10 started; log sequence number 1630842; transaction id 21
2018-10-16 15:07:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2018-10-16 15:07:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 181016 15:07:30
2018-10-16 15:07:30 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-10-16 15:07:30 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@localhost.localdomain' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-10-16 15:07:30 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeded
2018-10-16 15:07:30 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2018-10-16 15:07:30 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.3.10-MariaDB-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 0  MariaDB Server
```

I have below questions:
1.how to disable `[Note]` parts,actually I only need `[Error]`?
2.The end of log file is `port: 0  MariaDB Server`,Is that something wrong because port should be 3306.

Comment: Let's see your config file (`my.cnf` or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for check my `my.conf.d/server.cnf`  http://txt.do/dnfw8